# how to modify the routes?

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I have asp.net mvc project, and it's structure and routes are as below.

"Site.Master" include images and css files，with paths:

- ../../Images/1.gif
- ../../Content/site.css.

When visiting the page "http://www.localhost.com/Info/Index/1001", it works.

But page "http://www.localhost.com/Info/Index/1001/1" or "http://www.localhost.com/Info/Index/1001/2", don't.

I modified the images and css file path in the Site.Master like:

- /Images/1.gif
- /Content/site.css

In addition, is there another way to fix it？ or modify routes？ Because, i want deploy it using virtual directory in iis.

-> Images

- 1.gif
- 2.jpg

-> Content

- site.css

-> Views

- Home

  -- index.aspx
- Info

  -- index.aspx
- Shared

  -- Site.Master

  routes.MapRoute(
      "InfoPagedRoute",
      "{controller}/{action}/{classid}/{page}",
      new { controller = "Info", action = "Index", classid = @"\d{1,10}", page = 1 }
  );

Answer (score 0):

Your original route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "InfoPagedRoute",
     "{controller}/{action}/{classid}/{page}", 
     new { controller = "Info", action = "Index", classid = @"\d{1,10}", page = 1 } 
);
```

It looks like you are trying to use a validator in your route defaults for the classid, so either you need to include a validation parameter or set a default value for the classid.

I would suggest:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "InfoPagedRoute",
     "{controller}/{action}/{classid}/{page}", 
     new { controller = "Info", action = "Index", classid = 1001, page = 1 } 
);
```

If updating the route doesn't resolve the issue, you could use Phil Haack's [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).  It is really helpful in figuring out if the route you are expecting to get hit is actually the one that is being used.